# Lightning-input field wrap text

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I need some help on the below , i am trying to wrap the text in the below lightning input text field
<lightning-input

```
     placeholder="Search..."
    variant="label-hidden">
                                
    </lightning-input>
```

how to wrap the word in the next line , kindly help on this

Comment: add - `class="word-wrap: break-word;"`

Comment: didn't worked by adding above class

Answer (score 4):

The `lightning-input` does not support the multiline text. you need to use the `lightning-textarea`

```
<lightning-textarea name="input1" label="Enter some text" ></lightning-textarea>
```

[Textarea Documentations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-textarea/example)